# Rounding up numbers to the nearest hundredths in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

What is the best way to round a number up to the nearest hundredths?

For example if I have 100/3, that will equal 33.333333333...  I want to round to the nearest hundredths so that I have 33.34, not 33.33.

Currently I'm doing this:
Math.Ceiling(numberToRound * 100) / 100;

That seems to work, but is that a normal way to do it?

This is in a Silverlight windows phone application using C#.

Comment: 33.33 is closer to 100/3 than 33.34 What do you mean by nearest hundredths?

Comment: Sorry, my wording might be too vague.  I want to round up to the nearest hundredths so that the number always goes up instead of down.  For example 33.331, 33.332, 33.333, 33.334, 33.335, 33.336... all round up to 33.34.

Comment: You should say "next hundredth"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round to the higher number, use `Math.Ceiling`. If you want to round to the lower number, use `Math.Floor`.

Drawback: those two functions don't take the number of digits as parameter, as does `Math.Round`. To get around, you can multiply your number first, round it, then divide it back.

For instance, to keep two decimals and round to the higher number:

```
var result = Math.Ceiling(number * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

> 33.33 is closer to 100/3 than 33.34 What do you mean by nearest hundredths?
>
> Sorry, my wording might be too vague. I want to round up to the
> nearest hundredths so that the number always goes up instead of down.
> For example 33.331, 33.332, 33.333, 33.334, 33.335, 33.336... all
> round up to 33.34.

Then using Ceiling is absolutely fine IF you want to round off the number.

If you just want to DISPLAY a maximum number of figures you should format the output instead of rounding.

In that case I would use a Value converter in Silverlight containing the correct conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.Round: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k(v=vs.95).aspx

Math.Round(33.3333D, 2) will result in 33.33.

Comment: I don't want 33.33 I want it to always round up to the nearest hundredths so the result in this case would be 33.34.

Answer (score 0):

You approach sounds fine to me - but I do wonder why you are doing this? Typically you only round numbers when they are displayed, otherwise you risk introducing rounding errors into your algorithms. How about using string formatting instead?

```
double myNumber = 100.0 / 3.0;
string myNumberFormatted = myNumber.ToString("N2"); // = "33.34"
```

Comment: myNumberFormatted results in "33.33", not "33.34" when I try this.